# How to Limit what fields are searchable in Algolia index in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, algolia

My data is structured like this

```
firstName: String
lastName: String
username: String
userID: String
school: String
```

****EDIT: This is my front end code if that helps, maybe the problem lies here.

```
 let index = client.index(withName: "Users")
       index.setSettings([
            "searchableAttributes": [
                "firstName",
                "lastName",
                "username"
            ]
            ])
        let query = Query(query: searchBar.text)
      //  query.facets = ["firstName", "username", "lastName"]
        index.search(query, completionHandler: { (content, error) -> Void in
         // completion handler//print results
        })
```

When I index this, I only want to get results with the firstName, lastName, and username fields. I DO NOT want algolia to look through the userID and school fields for this particular search

I've tried changing the facets and the searchable attributes but nothing seems to change.

My results have been searching through every single field, not just the ones I specified. Maybe I just don't have a great understanding of how algolia queries work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While indexing you should set which attributes are searchable.

```
index.setSettings([
  "searchableAttributes": [
    "firstName",
    "lastName",
    "username"
  ]
])
```

See this [link](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/searchableAttributes/) for more details.

Although setting the `searchableAttributes` should work, you can also restrict your attributes

```
query.restrictSearchableAttributes = [
  "firstName",
  "lastName",
  "username"
]
```

See this [link](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/restrictSearchableAttributes/) for restricting your attributes for a query

Comment: I added that, but it seems that it is still indexing all of the fields. Maybe I've forgotten a critical step? I added my front end code to the question because I may be doing something wrong here.

Comment: I now get the error "Optional("invalid setting for restrictSearchableAttributes, attribute firstName is not in searchableAttributes setting")". I really think there is something fundamentally wrong with my code/setup with algolia

Comment: The error is that `firstName` is not in the list of `searchableAttributes` for some reason. Can you check your algolia dashboard once to see your settings ?

Comment: I see what the problem was. I needed to set the searchable attributes when I created the index, not when I was querying through the index. I solved the problem by adding all the attributes to that index's searchable attributes in the algolia dashboard and then using the query.restrictSearchableAttributes method. Thank you for the help